# Xamarin Forms - Send event to native and retrieve value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently making a custom view to preview camera of the device, and trying to trigger a "take picture" event.

Right now, i can trigger the event, but i don't find a solution to return the picture to Xamarin Forms Shared Code.

Here's what i'm doing from the **Xamarin Forms custom control** :

```
public class CameraPreview : View
{
    public event EventHandler TakePictureRequested;

    public void TakePicture()
    {
        TakePictureRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And here from **Native code for Android for example** :

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            e.OldElement.TakePictureRequested += OnTakePictureRequested;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreviewView(Context);
                SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
            }
            Control.Preview = Camera.Open(getBackCameraId());

            e.NewElement.TakePictureRequested += OnTakePictureRequested;
        }
    }

    void OnTakePictureRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cameraPreview.TakePicture();
    }
```

The idea is that "OnTakePictureRequested" from Native Code can return the value to the Xamarin Forms.

Anyone has an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netstandard-2.0). Its pretty straight forward, if you still need help we can take a look at what you've tried

Comment: Hello @shanranm , I already tried it, but it seems i can't return something from an Invoke

Comment: You need to await the Task returned by `TaskCompletionSource`

Comment: Yes but it can't work for an Event Handler. Invoke is a void function and cannot be awaited. What i want, is retrieving the information in my Custom control.

Comment: what value you want to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your native view access Xamarin Forms view by

```cs
var xamarinFormsView = e.NewElement as CameraPreview;
xamarinFormsView .DoSomethingAfterPictureTaken("blahblah");
```

and in `CameraPreview` add a method to access and do something with the value you want to send over

```cs
void DoSomethingAfterPictureTaken(string valueFromNative){
//access valuefromNative as you wish
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try to use `MessagingCenter` to pass the value

Xamarin.Forms `MessagingCenter` enables view models and other components to communicate without having to know anything about each other besides a simple Message contract.It is a static class with Subscribe and Send methods that are used throughout the solution.

you just need `Subscribe` it in your `CameraPreview`

then `Send` the value from your `CustomRenderer`.

you could refer to [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)